# Connecting sqlite db on server

Tags: php, html, sqlite, server

So I have a website created with html, javascript, sqlite, and php. It runs fine on localhost. I moved it to an actual server and now it wont load because the path to the database is different and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have tried changing the link but the server folder has '\' in it so php doesnt seem to like that.

The PHP code is below:
On localhost it was

```
$database_name = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/proj/db/radar.db"
```

the path to the server is "\proj\company.net$"
I tried `$database_name = "\\proj\company.net$/db/radar.db"`

It just doesn't load anything an I know the back or forward slashes are throwing it off but i'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure its mysql?

Comment: use double backslashes for each backslash

Comment: @GiacomoM sorry brainfart yes I meant sqlite. I edited it.

Comment: Apart from the string syntax, this requires proper mounting or permissions: [php access network path under windows](//stackoverflow.com/q/1153824)

Answer (score 0):

You need to scape the backslashes.
if you need `\\proj\company.net$/db/radar.db`
then your code should look like this:
`$database_name = "\\\\proj\\company.net$/db/radar.db";`